# PHP Mysql table fetch only gives first row

Tags: php, mysql

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM pass";
$result = mysql_query($query,$conn);
echo mysql_num_rows($result);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $username = $row['user'];
    $password = $row['pass'];   
}
```

Num rows = 12 but while loops only the first one if I use in while `$row = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pass",$conn))`

If i use the first code it gives error after the first row,
*Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in*

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It's awful and has been removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) helps explain best practices. Make **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will end up with severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 1):

you define the variables wrong if you don't give it a number it will always only have 1 result and do some reading about newer ways to connect to mysql database

```
$i = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $username[$i] = $row['user'];
    $password[$i] = $row['pass'];   
    $i++;
}

//you can test like this
$r = 0;
while($r < $i)
{
    echo $username[$r];
    echo $password[$r];
    $r++;
}
```

Comment: @katates see my edit i missed something change fetch array to mysql_fetch_assoc

Comment: Thats weird now it only gets the first char, edit: solved it!

Comment: might because your table name is the same as your column name also do you have mysql_select_db("your data base name") line after you connected to the data base but before the query? and this line i believe should be this $result = mysql_query($query);